# Factoring expressions of surds

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I factorize expressions like `(Sqrt[2] + 2Sqrt[3]+2)^2 (2-Sqrt[3])` to `(2Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3]-1)^2`?

Comment: With `z = (Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[3] + 2)^2 (2 - Sqrt[3])` you can ask for `FullSimplify[Sqrt[z]]` but this means that you'd have to know the exponent beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = (Sqrt[2] + 2 Sqrt[3] + 2)^2 (2 - Sqrt[3]);

expr2 = expr /. x_?(Positive[N[#]] &)*(y_)^2 :> 
  (FullSimplify[Sqrt[x]*y])^2

(* (-1 + 2 Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[3])^2 *)

expr == expr2

(* True *)
```

Comment: Generalizing, if we have an expression being an algebraic number, is it easy to determine if these can be factorized or not?

Comment: Ask a mathematician